# how to make a table header/banner responsive with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a table banner/header responsive re sizing depending on the window size. The layout shows how I want to keep the design of the banner/header even though they would re-size every time it the windows adjusts.
this is how the layout look looks:

[image]

or same layout design just adjusted the window

[image]

and this is the code that I have so far:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table border="0" width="100%" height=60  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-condenseď">
    <tr>
        <td width="200">
            <a href="http://www.example.com" target=_blank>
                <img src="img1.png" width="200" height="100" >
            </a>
        </td>
        <td  width="15" height="38" >
            <img src="img2.png" width="39" height="33" >
        </td>

        <td  width="100" style="color:white; font-weight: bold; color:blue;">
            <font size="3"></font>
            <font size="5">
                <?php echo $_SESSION['login']; ?>
            </font>
         </td>
        <td  width="600" height="45" >
            <img src="img3.PNG" width="900" height="100" >
        </td>

        <td width="100" height="45" >
            <ul>
                <font color="blue" size="2">
                    <?php echo date(" d F Y ",time());?>
                </font>
                <li >
                    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

I have tried this code but I get all the images in their original size and all of them stacking on top of each other in a small window.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
                <img src="img1.png"  >
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <img src="img2.png" >
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <font size="3"></font>
        <font size="5">
            <?php echo $_SESSION['login']; ?>
        </font>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="img3.PNG" >
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <ul>
            <font color="blue" size="2">
                <?php echo date(" d F Y ",time());?>
            </font>
            <li >
                <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Those hardcoded widths on the table are most likely interfering with what you are trying to accomplish. Simply adding the "table-reponsive" class doesn't mean everything will work correctly out of the box. Side note: Don't use the old <font> tag, and don't apply color right to it like that, use CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using grid as below

```css
.col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-5{
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-left:none;
  height:70px;
}


.test:first-child {
   border-left:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container-fluid" style="margin:12px;">
<div class="row test">
  <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-5"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
</div>
</div>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do I keep the images from expanding to their normal size?

Comment: You can use "img-responsive" class for images

e.g.  <img class="img-responsive" src="img.jpg" alt="image">

Answer (score 0):

Please don't define custom widths for td

The .table-responsive class creates a responsive table which will scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px).

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Table</h2>
  <p>my Table</p>                                                                                      
  <div class="table-responsive">          
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Andy</td>
        <td>Stuart</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>Sydney</td>
        <td>Australia</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how do I assign a fixed size so that i can get the table to be like the one i mentioned re sizing every time with the same layout, but re sizing depending on the resolution. @Arun

Comment: You can use bootstrap grid

Comment: I have tried it with bootstrap grid but I'm not getting what I want. How can I fix this?

Comment: Check my last posted answer. It works perfectly fine even if you resize and zoom in. You have to use col-xs so that it doesn't collapse in mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you followed the documentation on [Bootstrap responsive tables](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive) correctly. I'm not sure what your question is though. If you are looking for the columns to move more fluently, you might consider getting rid of the width attributes.

If you are looking to create a responsive layout in the traditional sense with elements collapsing for smaller and smaller views then Bootstrap has [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) on using their existing navbar. Tables were popular in the 90's for layout and placement but div's are the new kid on the block, especially when it comes to responsive layouts. Here is the example from their documentation:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```